# Remove item[i] from jQuery each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove an item[i] from items once it reaches in:

```
$.each(items, function(i) {
    // how to remove this from items
});
```

Comment: What is your goal? If you want to remove every item from `items`, just set `items` to an empty array.

Comment: I don't have to do this anymore... because I had to re-run my javascript function without realising the actual issue why it was timing out in non-IE browsers:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71305

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to remove an element from array, use `splice()`

```
var myArray =['a','b','c','d'];
var indexToRemove = 1;
// first argument below is the index to remove at, 
//second argument is num of elements to remove
myArray.splice(indexToRemove , 1);
```

`myArray` will now contain `['a','c','d']`

Comment: the question was how to remove it from a loop.

Comment: @CiprianTarta the question was clearly ill formatted since this answered it for op... But I agree. Using splice doesn't really work when it's inside any `$.each` loop as it will mess up the loop.

Answer (score 120):

It would be better not to use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) in this case. Use [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) instead.  This loops through an array in pretty much the same way as `$.each` with one exception.  If you return `true` from the callback, the element is retained. Otherwise, it is removed from the array.

Your code should look something like this:

```
items = $.grep(items, function (el, i) {
    if (i === 5) { // or whatever
        return false;
    }

    // do your normal code on el

    return true; // keep the element in the array
});
```

One more note: `this` in the context of a `$.grep` callback is set to `window`, not to the array element.

Comment: Pretty sure `$.grep()` is only for Arrays. If `items` is an Array, it would be good as long as there aren't any other references to the Array that are expecting the updated version. :o)

Comment: Just to note for others. el is the element i is just the index.

Comment: el and i other way around compared to each

Comment: As mentioned `grep` is for Arrays, but you could insert your selector inside `grep`:
<pre>
`items = $.grep($(".myselector", function (el, i) {`
`    return (i===5) ? false : true;`
` };`
</pre>

Comment: Just clarifying @user113716's very important comment: `$.grep` does _not_ modify the array; it simply returns a copy of the array, potentially sans some (or all of its) elements.

Comment: Using splice inside $.each loop threw errors in  my code. Refactoring to $.grep fixed the problem! Thanks a lot for the tip.

Answer (score 11):

I'm guessing you want `$.map`. You can `return null` to remove an item, and not worry about how indices might shift:

```
items = $.map(items, function (item, index) {
    if (index < 10) return null; // Removes the first 10 elements;
    return item;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

the solution is below:

```
_.each(data, function (item, queue) {
    if (somecondition) {
        delete data[queue]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
var indexToBeRemoved = 3; // just an illustration
$.each(items, function(i) {
    if(i==indexToBeRemoved){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: If what the OP wants to do is remove an element from the DOM, then this is correct. If he wants to just remove an item from the list, then this won't do that.

Comment: Yes, I assumed it is a DOM element, otherwise what is the point of using jquery....

Comment: The point of using `JQuery` might be iterating a `json` object.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @lonesomday above (I simply couldn't add this in a comment) `grep` is for Arrays, but you could insert your selector inside `grep`:

```
var items = $.grep($(".myselector", function (el, i) {
  return (i===5) ? false : true;
};
```

This would store all elements found using `$(".myselector")`in ìtems` leaving out the item at the 6th position (the list is 0 indexed, which makes "5" the 6th element)

Answer (score 1):

Although I would typically prefer using `$.grep()` to filter the array, I have an instance where I'm already using `$.each()` on the array to process a dataset. After doing some processing, I can determine whether or not the item needs to be removed from the array:

```
// WARNING - DON'T DO THIS:
$.each(someArray, function(index, item) {
    // Some logic here, using 'item'

    if (removeItem) {
        // Spice this item from the array
        someArray.splice(index, 1)
    }

    // More logic here
});
```

**WARNING:** This presents a new problem! Once the item has been spliced from the array, jQuery will still loop for the length of the original array. E.g.:

```
var foo = [1,2,3,4,5];

$.each(foo, function(i, item) {
    console.log(i + ' -- ' + item);
    if (i == 3){ 
        foo.splice(i, 1); 
    }
});
```

Will output:

```
0 -- 1
1 -- 2
2 -- 3
3 -- 4
4 -- undefined
```

And foo is now `[1, 2, 3, 5]`.  Every item in the array is "shifted" relative to the jQuery loop, and we missed the element "5" altogether, and the last item in the loop is `undefined`.  The **best** way to solve this is to use a reverse `for` loop (going from `arr.length - 1` to `0`). 
 This will ensure that removing an element won't affect the next item in the loop. However since the question here is with respect to $.each, there are a few alternative ways of solving this:

**1) `$.grep()` the array before looping**

```
var someArray = $.grep(someArray, function(item) {
    // Some logic here, using 'item'

    return removeItem == false;
});

$.each(someArray, function(index, item) {
    // More logic here
});
```

**2) Push items into another array**

```
var choiceArray = [ ];

$.each(someArray, function(index, item) {
    // Some logic here, using 'item'

    if (removeItem) {
        // break out of this iteration and continue
        return true; 
    }

    // More logic here

    // Push good items into the new array
    choiceArray.push(item);
});
```