# Remove value in jquery each

Tags: jquery

How can I remove value in each(). In element.name it contain value, abc,cde,efg,hig,xyx. I want to remove cde,efg.

```
 $.each(data, function(index, element) {
   var cat_title = element.name;
   $('.my_lists').append("<option>"  + cat_title + "</option>");
 });
```

Comment: `element.name.replace('cde,efg,', '')`

Comment: After `var cat_title = element.name;` do `console.log(cat_title);` and show us what it outputs (not all but first three output)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove item\[i\] from jQuery each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869292/remove-itemi-from-jquery-each-loop)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip cde and efg values for your list do this

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
   var cat_title = element.name;
   if(cat_title == 'cde' || cat_title == 'efg')
     return; //skip to next iteration
   $('.my_lists').append("<option>"  + cat_title + "</option>");
 });
```

Comment: Mudassir Hasan this will be more ok:-`$.each(data, function(index, element) {
   var cat_title = element.name;
   if(cat_title !== 'cde' && cat_title !== 'efg')
 $('.my_lists').append("<option>"  + cat_title + "</option>");
 });`