# Unable to delete an array element using splice in jQuery $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have an object which has only one property as "contacts" and its value is an array which contains 4 objects and each object has properties like email, firstname etc...

I want to remove a particular object from that array by matching its email property with an given email.

I am trying to iterate through that array using $.each loop in jQuery and trying to match email in each iteration and when matched I am trying to delete that object using splice but it is not working.

**Below is a sample code similar to what I am implementing:**

```
//main object with all the data
var data = {
    "contacts": [
    {
        "email": "jonas.sultani@hellyhansen.com",
        "firstname": "Jonas",
        "lastname": "Sultani",
        "prefix": "Mr",
        "title": "Consultant",
        "company": "Helly Hansen",
        "phone": "+49 6245 99334",
        "fax": "+49 6245 99335"
    },
    {
        "email": "james.simmons@boeing.com",
        "firstname": "James H",
        "lastname": "Simmons",
        "prefix": "Mr",
        "title": "AP Lead",
        "company": "Boeing",
        "phone": "+1 112-445-6684",
        "fax": ""
    },
    {
        "email": "slmarino@boehringer-ingelheim.com",
        "firstname": "Stephanie",
        "lastname": "Marino",
        "prefix": "Mrs",
        "title": "Project Manager",
        "company": "Boehringer Ingelheim",
        "phone": "+1 650-554-5124",
        "fax": ""
    }
    ]
}

//extracting array from the data object
var myArray = data.contacts;

//sample email to match and delete the object
var email = "jonas.sultani@hellyhansen.com";

//function to delete the object containing the passed email
function deleteElement(myId){

    //iterating the myArray to check the email with the given email
    $.each(myArray, function(key, val){

        var email = val.email;

        //if the email is matched the particular object on the current index  in the array is deleted using splice
        if(myId === email){
            myArray.splice(key,1);
            return;
        }
    });
}

//calling the function and passing the email to delete the object
deleteElement(email);

//printing the modified array
console.log(myArray);
```

This method is not working so can you please let me know how can I make this work.

**Note**: I don't want to modify anything with the data object or myArray but I want to find solution with the current situation

Big Thanks

Comment: If you mutate the array within the loop you are changing the meaning of the indexes, since the positions change. The result may be anything depending on the implementation details of `$.each()`. How about ES 2015 array methods `map` and `filter` and creating a new array?

Comment: You could try  `$.grep()` as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4869347/3450689

Comment: yes but just want to break on the first condition met so thought to just iterate, match, delete and break. I don't want to continue with the shuffled array in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `do..while` loop or `while` loop to remove elements from an array within a loop

```
let i = 0;

let len = data.contacts.length;

do {
  var email = data.contact[i].email;
  if (myId === email) {
    data.contacts.splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
  ++i;
} while (i < len);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against the use of jQuery (because you don't need it) and against any for/while loop, and just KISS it :

```
function deleteElementWithEmail(data, email) {
    return data.filter(function (current) {
      return current.email !== email
    })
}
```

With all your code:

```
//main object with all the data
var data = {
    "contacts": [
    {
        "email": "jonas.sultani@hellyhansen.com",
        "firstname": "Jonas",
        "lastname": "Sultani",
        "prefix": "Mr",
        "title": "Consultant",
        "company": "Helly Hansen",
        "phone": "+49 6245 99334",
        "fax": "+49 6245 99335"
    },
    {
        "email": "james.simmons@boeing.com",
        "firstname": "James H",
        "lastname": "Simmons",
        "prefix": "Mr",
        "title": "AP Lead",
        "company": "Boeing",
        "phone": "+1 112-445-6684",
        "fax": ""
    },
    {
        "email": "slmarino@boehringer-ingelheim.com",
        "firstname": "Stephanie",
        "lastname": "Marino",
        "prefix": "Mrs",
        "title": "Project Manager",
        "company": "Boehringer Ingelheim",
        "phone": "+1 650-554-5124",
        "fax": ""
    }
    ]
}

//extracting array from the data object
var myArray = data.contacts;

//sample email to match and delete the object
var email = "jonas.sultani@hellyhansen.com";

//function to delete the object containing the passed email
    function deleteElementWithEmail(data, email) {
        return data.filter(function (current) {
          return current.email !== email
        })
    }

//calling the function and passing the email to delete the object
myArray = deleteElementWithEmail(myArray, email);

//printing the modified array
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.filter` function to get desired result.

```js
//main object with all the data
var data = {
  "contacts": [{
      "email": "jonas.sultani@hellyhansen.com",
      "firstname": "Jonas",
      "lastname": "Sultani",
      "prefix": "Mr",
      "title": "Consultant",
      "company": "Helly Hansen",
      "phone": "+49 6245 99334",
      "fax": "+49 6245 99335"
    },
    {
      "email": "james.simmons@boeing.com",
      "firstname": "James H",
      "lastname": "Simmons",
      "prefix": "Mr",
      "title": "AP Lead",
      "company": "Boeing",
      "phone": "+1 112-445-6684",
      "fax": ""
    },
    {
      "email": "slmarino@boehringer-ingelheim.com",
      "firstname": "Stephanie",
      "lastname": "Marino",
      "prefix": "Mrs",
      "title": "Project Manager",
      "company": "Boehringer Ingelheim",
      "phone": "+1 650-554-5124",
      "fax": ""
    }
  ]
}

//extracting array from the data object
var myArray = data.contacts;
//console.log(myArray);
//sample email to match and delete the object
var email = "jonas.sultani@hellyhansen.com";

//function to delete the object containing the passed email
function deleteElement(myId) {
  myArray = myArray.filter(function(el) {
    return el.email != myId;
  });
}

//calling the function and passing the email to delete the object
deleteElement(email);

//printing the modified array
console.log(myArray);
```